# SpeechRecognizer does nothing...what am I missing

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

Please see the code below. onBeginningOfSpeech() gets called (even before I start speaking, BTW), but then - nothing. What am I missing?

I admit that the code is mostly composed of different examples, which I do not fully understand. But I would expect it to do at least something, so that I can continue experimenting. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class SpeechRecogActivity extends Activity {
private SpeechRecognizer recog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("TTS_SpeechRecog", "Starting...");
        recog = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        recog.setRecognitionListener(new RecogListener());
        Intent intent = RecognizerIntent.getVoiceDetailsIntent(getApplicationContext());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "cmn-Hans-CN");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "cmn-Hans-CN");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "cmn-Hans-CN");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, "com.dummy");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
        recog.startListening(intent);
    }

    private static class RecogListener implements RecognitionListener {
        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            Log.e("TTS_SpeechRecog", "onBeginningOfSpeech...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
            Log.e("TTS_SpeechRecog", "onRmsChanged...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            Log.e("TTS_SpeechRecog", "onEndOfSpeech...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            Log.e("TTS_SpeechRecog", "onReadyForSpeech...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle data) {
            Log.e("TTS_SpeechRecog", "onResults...");
            ArrayList strlist = data.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            for (int i = 0; i < strlist.size();i++ ) {
                Log.d("Speech", "result=" + strlist.get(i));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
            Log.e("TTS_SpeechRecog", "onPartialResults...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
            Log.e("TTS_SpeechRecog", "onEvent...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
            Log.e("TTS_SpeechRecog", "onBufferReceived...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {
            Log.e("TTS_SpeechRecog", "onBeginningOfSpeech...");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to add permission.

`android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO`

Before API 23 u can just add:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`

After API 23 use runtime permissions.

Comment: Adding "    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
" indeed did the trick!

Comment: It is extremely weird, though, that "startActivityForResult()" with "RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH" did work without such permissions!

Any idea why?

Answer (score -1):

You have to start SpeechRecognizer after click on any button or widget.

I would recommend you to use below github repository.

https://github.com/gotev/android-speech

Also ensure that you have added permission in menifest like :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: Hmm...effectively, this is exactly what is happening - a user clicks a button (in a different Activity) and then this activity gets called... isn't this enough?

Comment: yes it will call as you click a button. This is default behavior.

Comment: As I just said...a button is getting clicked. And yet it's not working.

Comment: do you mean it doesn't recognize your voice? Also make sure your internet is on